# Show post from other database in admin page wordpress

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I have a database that stores shared data (DB2) like posts and some other things and a website using wordpress. I want to display all posts from DB2 according to query filter in the custom post type section in the admin interface wordpress. Is there any way I can do that?

I tried creating a custom post type, then creating a post with the same slug as the DB2 post, it works but only uniquely, I want to do it automatically and in bulk.

Comment: Is this second database also a WP database - or does it have its own, arbitrary structure?

Comment: _"I tried creating a custom post type, then creating a post with the same slug as the DB2 post, it works but only uniquely"_ - it "works" in what way, exactly? I don't see how having a post with the same slug in your WP database, has anything to do with actually accessing data from that second database ...?

Comment: It is a separately structured database, do I need to intervene directly in wp-admin to do this or just use wordpress's available code?

Comment: You should not start manipulating any WP core files, all this needs to be done using whatever hooks are available around the backend functionality. Making a connection to a different database is quite easy, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1618